# How is Chat's "frequently in room" sorted?

Tags: support, chat

In a [chat room info page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/95/english-language-and-usage), users can be sorted according to "frequently in room". What does this order actually do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how it currently works:

> Take all users who
>
> 1. have spoken in the room within the last two weeks, and
> 2. whose messages in the room are more than one percent of all messages here,
>
> and sort them (in descending order) by their percentage of activity in this room (as in 2.) divided by the how long ago they last spoke. Take the top ten resulting users.

There's no guarantee this formula won't ever change, but it's been like this for a while, and its results are usually pretty good.

Comment: Did it change in those last four years? We had a discussion about it today in the Tavern, and I now found this post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, hasn't changed. That's still how it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much *sort* order, as it is more primarily a listing. It says in the tooltip:

> Users who are regularly active in this room

As such, to differentiate it from "currently in room", it can include users who are not physically present at the immediate moment, yet are constant contributors.

I imagine it's sorted in some rough fashion based on that level of activity, the most active such users being listed at the top. This is probably based on activity time moreso than post count.

Comment: I realise that it is based on activity in some way, but I'm curious as to in _which_ way.